# How to fix "pool.map issues in python"

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'm trying to do multiprocessing in python. The task is to generate text files in a folder using pool.map. Could anyone give a brief explanation of whats wrong with the code and why is it going to some infinite loop without any activity happening?. Also, I couldn't use ctrl+c to quit the running program. I've provided a MWE. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
# =============================================================================
# Minimum Working Example
# =============================================================================
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

path=os.getcwd() # address of current working directory
# =============================================================================
basemodel='Example_SS1' # Enter the basemodel name

try:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, basemodel)) # create a directory if do not exists
except Exception:
    pass # if existing, pass on (i.e. continue)
# =============================================================================
Hmax=[0.93,0.93,1.86,1.86,2.79,2.79,3.72,3.72,4.65,5.58] 
Tp=[3.88,6.46,5.17,7.75,6.46,9.04,7.75,10.34,9.04,10.34] 
drns=[0,30,60,90,120,150,180]
# =============================================================================
all_files=[]
count=1
for k in range(0,len(drns)):
    for i in range(0,len(Hmax)):
        file_name=str(str(count).zfill(2))+'_Hmax_'+str(Hmax[i])+'_Tp_'+str(Tp[i])+'_'+str(drns[k]) # filename syntax of loadcases
        print (file_name)
        all_files.append(file_name)
        count+=1 # loadcase number increment
# =============================================================================                
def todos(filename):
    lc_split=filename.split("_")
    lc_number=int(lc_split[0])
    lc_Hmax=float(lc_split[2])
    lc_Tp=float(lc_split[4])
    lc_drn=float(lc_split[5])      
    # =============================================================================
    file_name=str(str(lc_number).zfill(2))+'_Hmax_'+str(lc_Hmax)+'_Tp_'+str(lc_Tp)+'_'+str(lc_drn)+'.txt' # filename syntax of loadcases
    os.path.join(path, basemodel, file_name)
    print ('Loadcase '+file_name+' is created')
    # =============================================================================

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(24)
    pool.map(todos, all_files)
pool.close()
```

Comment: Are you running this from the command line or through an IDE? (If using an IDE, try running the script from the command line to eliminate one possible source of the problem.)

Comment: Are you seeing any output from the print statements? If so, what output? That would give us a clue about where in the script the code is hanging.

Comment: @unutbu: I'm just printing to see the filenames. I don't know what exactly is problem with the usage of pool.map() command in my code. I provided an MWE. Basically I'm expecting to see the new text files in the folder.